# Barrier implementation for inter process in shared memory

Tags: c++, c, synchronization, semaphore, barrier

I am looking for an inter-processes barrier implementation. Processes are in shared memory (ie. on the same ndoe).

Processes are MPI ones. I do not want to use the MPI_Barrier function, because the general policy for all the MPI implementation is active waiting. I want my processes sleeping as long as they wait.

The restrictions:

- should be in C, maybe in C++
- no spinlock, so it could use semaphore
- linux OS

I am confident it exists thousands of barrier implementation, but I do not find any?!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pthread_barrier`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_barrier_destroy.html) is the POSIX API for barriers. They may live in process shared memory if you [initialize](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_barrierattr_setpshared.html) them accordingly.

Comment: It sounds great! I give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Boost. I believe that it has an interprocess module that you can use.