# inter processes shared memory and pthread_barrier: how to be safe?

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, mmap

I wanted a simple solution for inter processes barrier. Here a solution: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461954/barrier-implementation-for-inter-process-in-shared-memory)

But I am totally lost with mmap... With my first try, it fails one out of ten times (segfault or deadlock).

I understand my problem comes from a synchronization issue, but I can't find it. I found an example to set up mmaped memory ([example](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/mmap-tutorial-c-c-511265/)), but I am not sure it is good for a mmaped pthread_barrier.

Here an extract of my code:

```
#define MMAP_FILE "/tmp/mmapped_bigdft.bin"

void init_barrier() {
  pthread_barrier_t *shared_mem_barrier;
  pthread_barrierattr_t barattr;
  pthread_barrierattr_setpshared(&barattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

  hbcast_fd = open(MMAP_FILE, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0600);
  result = lseek(hbcast_fd, sizeof(pthread_barrier_t)-1, SEEK_SET);
  result = write(hbcast_fd, "", 1);
  shared_mem_barrier = (pthread_barrier_t*) mmap(0, sizeof(pthread_barrier_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, hbcast_fd, 0);
  if (mpi_rank == 0) {
    int err = pthread_barrier_init(shared_mem_barrier, &barattr, host_size);
  }
  MPI_Barrier(some_communicator);
}
```

Questions:

- do I miss something in mmap initialization?
- which operation should be performed by all processes, and which should be by only one?

**New question**

Which is safier for managing pthread barrier? Or are they based on the same mechanism?

- shmget
- shm_open
- mmap
- another one

Answer (score 2):

As Charles has mentioned, it looks like the truncation is what's getting you. Also, you should initialise the attributes using pthread_barrierattr_init.

As for the other question, just one process should do the initialisation, and then all processes should call pthread_barrier_wait (just like with MPI).

I saw your other question, so I know why you don't want to use MPI. So you'd probably do just a single MPI barrier to initialise your pthread barriers, like so:

```
if (rank == 0)
{
  /* Create the shared memory segment, initialise the barrier. */
}
MPI_Barrier(communicator);
if (rank != 0)
{
  /* Load the shared memory segment, cast it to a pthread_barrier_t* and store.
   * It's already initialised */
}
```

Comment: Which shared memory method would you use?

Comment: The last time I needed to do interprocess barriers, I used MPI ;) POSIX shared memory should be fine, which is what you're using already. You just need to stop the other processes from accessing the shared memory before it's been initialised properly.

Comment: My questions was about which shared memory paradigm should I use for a pthread_barrier: mmap, shmget, another one?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the initial code properly. I would've used shm_open.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to open the file with O_TRUNC for every process. Every time you do that, you'll truncate the file again and potentially invalidate the previous mmap operations you've performed (the affect on previous mmap's when changing the file size is generally undefined).

That aside, I don't think you can have a semaphore in a mmap'd memory and have it function correctly (it may on some OS platforms, so I doubt it's generally guaranteed to function the way you want).

What you really want to use is shared memory. Do man on " shmget" and "shmat" to learn how to create and map shared memory. You'll probably still need a file to pass the shared memory ID around, and you should be careful about freeing a shared memory ID during application crashes by registering signal handlers. Otherwise you can leave zombie shared memory allocations sitting around and overrun your OS resource limits. You'll know that happened if you get ENOSPC when attempting to create the shared memory segment on your master thread.

Comment: Do you have a pointer explaining all that? You said that mmap is not the best for pthread_barrier. shmget is better? Do you have another in mind?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `shm_open` to create a shared segment.

- With the paramenter `O_CREAT` you
  should be able to detect if a process
  is the first to create the segment.
- Only that process should trunctate
  the segment to the appropriate length, map it
  and initialize the barrier.
- All the others that detect that they
  are not the first should sleep for a
  while, a second or so should suffice, and then map the segment.
- After that all processes may
  synchronize of the barrier.